# Build netbeans web project and include webserver

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, netbeans, webserver

I have made a web project in netbeans 6.9.1 and Im using tomcat 6. Its just a test project, I would like to know how to build the project to include tomcat and everything, I want to be able to run the whole app on a computer that just has the java re and sdk like a .jar file for a normal project, is there a way to do this? so far I have made a .war file which apparently contains all files but not tomcat

Comment: I basicly want something like this setup: http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp where a webserver is included in the actual application, is there any way to do this? Even without tomcat? I want to be able to run a .jar webserver and it must serve my .jsp files wherever

Answer (score 0):

There is no "clean" solution, basically the only thing you can do is pack up the Tomcat folder and copy that one too. Keep in mind that you may need to set the enviroment variables for CATALINA_HOME/BASE.

Comment: You can try setting it up starting from this: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html#Unix_daemon. There is no predefined solution though, and since Tomcat is a rather large application (well, relatively speaking) it's not easy to have it run from a jar.